# Using * idiom to unpack arguments when using map()

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Is there a way to unpack a tuple with the `*` idiom when using the `map` built-in in Python?

Ideally, I'd like to do the following:

```
def foo(a, b):
  return a**2 + b

x = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

results = map(foo, *x)
```

where results would equal `[3, 13, 31]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `itertools.starmap`:

```
def foo(a, b):
  return a**2 + b

x = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

from itertools import starmap

starmap(foo, x)
Out[3]: <itertools.starmap at 0x7f40a8c99310>

list(starmap(foo, x))
Out[4]: [3, 13, 31]
```

Note that even in python 2, `starmap` returns an iterable that you have to manually consume with something like `list`.

Answer (score 1):

An uglier way than the @roippi's way...

```
x = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

map(lambda y:y[0]**2 + y[1], x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, `map` accepts *args, so your original call `map(foo, *x)` doesn't *immediately* fail - but what happens is that each element from `x` is treated as a sequence of values for one argument to `foo` - so it attempts `foo(1, 3, 5)` and would then attempt `foo(2, 4, 6)` except of course that `foo` only accepts 2 arguments.

Since we can see that our input `x` is effectively the "matrix transpose" of what we would like to feed in, that directly points us to a workaround:

```
>>> list(map(foo, *zip(*x))) # list() wrapping for 3.x support
[3, 13, 31]
```

... But don't do that. Use `itertools.starmap`; it's built for this and considerably clearer about your intent.